# reading a wav file using scipy.io.wavfile and then writing doesn't reproduce the original file

Tags: python, io, scipy, wav

I am trying to work with wav files in Python.
I downloaded the SciPy library which supposedly can do the job.
To see that it works I'm trying to read a wav file and then write it again to disk.
For some reason the new wav file that is created is not similar to the old one.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
(rate,sample) = wav.read("/vocal.wav")
wav.write("/temp.wav", rate, sample)
```

Comment: what's the difference? Quality ?

Comment: What happens if you read the `/temp.wav` file then write it to another temp file ?

Comment: The difference is that the temp.wav contains a strong white noise and a fuzzier and quieter version of the original vocal.wav

Comment: and strangely enough if I read /temp.wav and write it to temp1.wav I get the same file (at least it sounds the same to me).

Comment: I just tried it on another wav sample that I have and it worked fine. Perhaps there was something wrong with the vocals.wav file.

Answer (score 1):

> scipy.io.wavfile.write(filename, rate, data) : Writes a simple
>   uncompressed WAV file.
>   (From [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html))

I suspect that your input file has some kind of compression.

Comment: Compression should throw an exception ([source of wavfile.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/io/wavfile.py#L39))

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with **SciPy**, but according to the documentation of [`scipy.io.wavfile.write`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) the array do be written is expected to be an array of `int` type values. While [`scipy.io.wavfile.read`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) tells that type of the array is determined by the type of data in the file. They may not be the same.

It would be good, to read the written file once again and check if the array read from original contains the same date after conversion to `int`.